# как XSS атака затрагивает других пользователей

Tags: javascript, безопасность, xss

Просмотрел различные материалы по `XSS` атаке (в том числе и многие вопросы здесь, на `stackoverflow`)
но так и не понял принцип работы такой атаки

В примерах из описания приводят пример по типу
`http://some-url.com/xss?q=<script>alert(123)</script>`
Где вред может привести форма или url без экранирования символов

Но не понимаю **как этот код внедряется в браузеры других** пользователей?
В чём отличие от той же "игры" данными в инспекторе разработчика?

Comment: кинуть человеку ссылку по почте например, чтоб он перешел

Answer (score 2):

Я в своё время тоже долго не мог понять, как в итоге пострадает жертва.
Проблема многих описаний в том, что авторы сосредотачиваются на опасности, последствиях и т. д.

Постараюсь привести наглядный пример использования XSS уязвимости.

Допустим есть сайт `https://weak.com`
Допустим, если зайти на `https://weak.com/search?q=123`, то мы увидим страницу поиска и текст "найдено ... результатов по запросу '123'".
Т. е. все, что передаётся в адресной строке в параметре `q` выводится на странице поиска.
Т. е. на сайте сейчас например такая разметка:

```html
<div>
  "найдено ... результатов по запросу '123'"
</div>
```

Следовательно, если передать в параметре `q` что-то типа такого: `q=<script>alert(1)</script>`, то ВСЕ, КТО ПЕРЕЙДЁТ ПО ССЫЛКЕ `https://weak.com/search?q=<script>alert(1)</script>`

Получат следующий HTML:

```html
<div>
  "найдено ... результатов по запросу '<script>alert(1)</script>'"
</div>
```

Хакеру нужно не только найти уязвимость, но и как-то заманить пользователя по ссылке.
Как только пользователь переходит по ссылке, код `alert(1)` будет выполнен в браузере пользователя от имени пользователя.
Опасность в том, что если пользователь был авторизован на сайте `https://weak.com`, то вы можете слать любые запросы на сервер с куками пользователя. Сервер не может отличить легитимные запросы от нелегитимных.

То, что я описал выше - это "отражённый" (reflected) XSS. Т. е. от хакера требуется заманить жертву по специальной ссылке.

Существует ещё так называемая "хранимая" (stored) XSS.
Механизм срабатывания и последствия такие-же, как и при reflected XSS, но путь попадания отличается.
При stored XSS хакер один раз сохраняет в системе свой код, а потом система сама рассылает этот код пользователям.
Например, хакер пишет вредоносный комментарий и все, кто его откроет, выполнят у себя в браузере код хакера.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде тут в подзаголовке `Общая классификация XSS` очень простое объяснение [XSS атаки](https://wiki.rookee.ru/cross-site-scripting/). Простите, если уже читали отсюда и всё равно не стало понятно)